# Increment array key by one to provide add more functionality

Tags: php, mysql

> I want to increment `$quiz_option` by 1 like `$quiz_option1,$quiz_option2,$quiz_option3`.

Here i am providing add more functionality to insert answer into the database.
by using above option field I don't know how is it possible. I am using last insert id to perform the below task.

`$Quiz_ID = $quiz->insert();`

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_REQUEST['quiz_options']);$i++)
{                           
    $data=array
    (
        "quiz_Id"=>$Quiz_ID,
        "quiz_Options1"=>$_REQUEST['quiz_options'][$i]
        //To change in above line of code like quiz_Options1, quiz_Options2
    );
    $quiz->insertOptions($data,'quizoptions');
}
```

Comment: why not like this: `$data["quiz_options".++$count] = $_REQUEST['quiz_options'][$i];` use `count` variable before array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_REQUEST['quiz_options']);$i++)
{                           
    $data=array
    (
        "quiz_Id"=>$Quiz_ID,
        "quiz_Options".$i =>$_REQUEST['quiz_options'][$i]
        //To change in above line of code like quiz_Options1, quiz_Options2
    );
    $quiz->insertOptions($data,'quizoptions');
}
```

Comment: Please read my question properly. It mentioned that, want to increment key by 1 "quiz_Options1, quiz_Options2, quiz_Options3,"=>

Comment: Check the updated answer. Hope this is what was expected.

Comment: okk It's work fine ` "quiz_Options".$i =>$_REQUEST['quiz_options'][$i]`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
$Quiz_ID = $quiz->insert();

$data = array(
    "quiz_Id" => $Quiz_ID;
)

for($i=0; $i<count($_REQUEST['quiz_options']); $i++) {
    $key = "quiz_Options" . ($i+1);
    $data[$key] = $_REQUEST['quiz_options'][$i];
}

$quiz->insertOptions($data,'quizoptions');
```

A sample of $data (print_r($data)) will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [quiz_Id] => 111
    [quiz_Options1] => aaa
    [quiz_Options2] => bbb
    [quiz_Options3] => ccc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pre-increase one to `$i` before array start..

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_REQUEST['quiz_options']);$i++)
{
$key = $i;
$data=array
(
    "quiz_Id"=>$Quiz_ID,
    "quiz_Options".++$key =>$_REQUEST['quiz_options'][$i]
    //To change in above line of code like quiz_Options1, quiz_Options2
);
$quiz->insertOptions($data,'quizoptions');
}
```